# Rust: Validate a username and password against Active Directory?

Tags: rust

I want to validate a user/password against active directory. I found solution using .NET code (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement), but I can’t find the call made to the windows api. I know LogonUser in WinApi, but it validates the username/password on the specific host running the code. I want to validate a user against the active directory directly. Any idea ?

I have tried with LogonUser, but there is some cases where my user can't log on the host running the code calling LogonUser, but he can on other host of the domain so I want to accept that user.

Answer (score -1):

[Active Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) is Microsoft's implementation of the LDAP protocol, so any [LDAP crate](https://crates.io/search?q=ldap) should allow you to do what you want.